# Windows Forms - Randomize BackColor - Powershell

Tags: windows, forms, random, colors

I'm making a GUI using Windows Forms and I'd like to add a feature where you can randomize the background color of the form. Please be noted that I intend to keep the code fully written in Powershell.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$choochoo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

And here is the code that I need help with:

```
$choochoo.Add_Click({$objForm.BackColor = Random})
```

Obviously 'Random' does not work in this example and is only being used as a placeholder.

I suppose I need to generate random values using the time but would appreciate a more concrete code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to be using an instance of [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random) to select from the possible static properties of [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx).

Comment: I am amazed at how simple that was. You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Been learning Powershell recently. Playing around came up with a solution for this today if anyone wants to do all possible random colors (I know this thread is old).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Sample Form"
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "This is a Form."
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

function colorful{
    $c1 = '';
    $c2 = '';
    foreach( $digit in (1..6 | foreach{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })){
        $c1 = "$c1"+"$digit";}
    foreach( $digit in (1..6 | foreach{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })){
        $c2 = "$c2"+"$digit";}
    $Form.BackColor = "#FF"+$c1;
    $Form.ForeColor = "#FF"+$c2;
};
colorful;
$Form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this if someone needs this too:

```
function RandomBacklight {` 
$random = New-Object System.Random 
switch ($random.Next(9)) { 
    0 {$objForm.BackColor = "LightBlue"} 
    1 {$objForm.BackColor = "LightGreen"} 
    2 {$objForm.BackColor = "LightPink"} 
    3 {$objForm.BackColor = "Yellow"} 
    4 {$objForm.BackColor = "Orange"} 
    5 {$objForm.BackColor = "Brown"} 
    6 {$objForm.BackColor = "Magenta"} 
    7 {$objForm.BackColor = "White"} 
    8 {$objForm.BackColor = "Gray"} 

} 
}

$choochoo.Add_Click({RandomBacklight})
```